# how to add multiple blocks in tkinter - python

Tags: python, tkinter

i have the following block of code:

```
ttk.Label(self.tab, text='tab1', width = 10).grid(row=1, column=0)

login1 = Entry(self.tab)
login1.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx="20")

pwd1 = Entry(self.tab, show="*")
pwd1.grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx="20")

ttk.Label(self.tab, text='tab2', width = 10).grid(row=1, column=0)

login2 = Entry(self.tab)
login2.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx="20")

pwd2 = Entry(self.tab, show="*")
pwd2.grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx="20")
```

And don't know why but the second label overwrites the first one, I see only one label in the program.

Does anyone know what's causing this ?
My goal is to display some forms where user can fill up the form and save it into the file.

Will be thankful for your support,

Comment: The 2nd label is not overwriting the first one it is simply being placed on top of the first one. This is due to your grid row and column being the same for both labels.

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second label are in the same frame (`self.tab`) and grid in the same row (`row=1` for both) and column (`column=0` for both):

Please, change the row of the first label:

```
ttk.Label(self.tab, text='tab1', width = 10).grid(row=0, column=0)
```